# My Dashboard are different in Tableau Desktop and in Tableau Online

Tags: tableau-api

I'm a little stuck here, because the dashboards that I import are looking different on Tableau Online ( and so on on my website )
So on Tableau Desktop it looks like this:
[Tableau Desktop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC8Sz.png)

And after I upload it, it looks like this:
[Tableau Online screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtllw.png)

I already tried to remove every border line, add one but in blank...
I'm lost there since I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As the workbook is rendering in the browser there will often by small differences compared to the workbook on Tableau desktop.

These have been raised numerous times by the Tableau community, you may find the following useful as Tableau users discuss ways to generalize table formats to limit different rendering on desktop vs. online:
https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4113

Another option is to try disabling rendering on the published workbook, see this link in the official Tableau community:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/217263

Which suggests:

> Probably due to rendering. Try adding "?:render=false" at the end of
>   the URL.
>
> Example:
>
> /ViewName?:render=false

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I indeed tried what was said, but this does not work, since my problem is not during the rendering, but during the export to Tableau Online ( When i open them through the online editor i already see the changes)

Comment: Ah, then it sounds like the render setting will not fix this. I;d suggest contacting Tableau support, perhaps they can tell you exactly which elements of your workbook are causing these compatibility issues. Have you tried a different browser to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Yes i tried, and this does the same. I'll try to contact the support to see if they can help me fix this! Thanks for your help :)